# Haskell State Monad Coordinate

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, state-monad

I am trying to figure out how the state Monad works. I am trying to implement a function that gets two coordinates `(x, y)` and returns the `x` or `y` coordinate back. This should happen within the State Monad.

```
data Coordin = Coordin {x,y :: Float}
```

the functions that should be implemented they are looking like this:

```
getX :: State Coordin Float
getY :: State Coordin Float
```

How can this work out?

I have tried this:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }  

getX:: State Coordin Float
getX = State $ \(x, y) -> (x, (x, y))
```

but getting this error message :

```
Couldn't match type ‘(Float, t0)’ with ‘Coordin’
    Expected type: State Coordin Float
      Actual type: State (Float, t0) Float
    In the expression: State $ \ (x, y) -> (x, (x, y))
    In an equation for ‘getX’: getX = State $ \ (x, y) -> (x, (x, y))
```

Comment: Yeah, you can do that. Have you _tried_ anything yet?

Comment: yes but im just failing. i ve tried this : newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }  
getX:: State Coordin Float
getX = State $ \(x, y) -> (x, (x, y))

Comment: Ok that's something, now add it to the question and explain what goes wrong.

Comment: yes i did. i copy the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`State $ \(x, y) -> (x, (x, y))` has the type `State (Float,Float) Float`, which is indeed equivalent (*isomorphic*) to `State Coordin Float`, but it's not literally the same type. The `Coordin` type must be unwrapped with the `Coordin` constructor, not with the tuple constructor!

```
getX :: State Coordin Float
getX = State $ \(Coordin x y) -> (x, Coordin x y)
```

Alternatively, and preferrably, you can use the record field accessor:

```
getX = x <$> get
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!